# Which duration is billed in Vertex AI Pipeline, component duration or job duration?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using Vertex AI to run a custom pipeline with multiple components. Each component takes a few minutes for the job to be provisioned. When I click on a component, I see a duration, which starts from the moment the component was initialized ("waiting for job to be provisioned") until the end ("tearing down training program"). However, when I click on the view job button, I see the "elapsed time", which is shorter than the component duration.

I want to make sure I am not being charged for time that I am not actually using. I am confused about which of these durations will be billed. Will the "duration" of the component be billed or the "elapsed time" of the component job?  Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant Vertex AI Pipeline, According to this [discription](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing#pipelines) you are billed 0.03$ per execution, however this is separate from the billing to the resources that it is using and services that is called by the pipeline.

> Vertex AI Pipelines charges a run execution fee of $0.03 per Pipeline
> Run. You are not charged the execution fee during the Preview release.
> You also pay for Google Cloud resources you use with Vertex AI
> Pipelines, such as Compute Engine resources consumed by pipeline
> components (charged at the same rate as for Vertex AI training).
> Finally, you are responsible for the cost of any services (such as
> Dataflow) called by your pipeline.

You can also monitor your resources cost in the billing section of your project. You can view a full article here about billing reports [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports).